# Creating a new column conditional on the character values of two other columns

Tags: r

I am only a learner in R and have a fairly basic question.

I have a dataset called edata with two columns relevant to the posted question. These are GazeCue and TargetLocation. I wish to create a new column called CueType that shows as "Cued" or "Uncued" based on the values of the other two columns.

When GazeCue is equal to RightGazePic1.png and TargetLocation is equal to TargetR, the new CueType column should show as "Cued". Similarly when GazeCue is equal to LeftGazePic1.png and TargetLocation is equal to TargetL, the CueType column should again show as "Cued". Any other variation of values should show in CueType as "uncued".

An example of what I would like is pasted below.

```
GazeCue                  TargetLocation            CueType         

RightGazePic1.png        TargetR                   Cued             
LeftGazePic1.png         TargetL                   Cued             
RightGazePic1.png        TargetL                   Uncued           
LeftGazePic1.png         TargetR                   Uncued
```

I have been trying to complete this code using ifelse but with no luck. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty basic. One way would be to extract the L and R from both the png and the Target, and compare those using `ifelse`:

```
CueType <- ifelse(substr(GazeCue, 1,1) == substr(TargetLocation, 7,7),
                  "Cued",
                  "Uncued")
```

If the names can vary a bit more, take a look at `gsub` to extract the relevant information from the strings before making the comparison.

Comment: Editing your answer to substr(TargetLocation, 7,7) gave the desired outcome. Shows to a beginner like me how flexible R can be. Once again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Rstudent obviously... it's friday, my counting isn't as good as at the start of the week :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of the fact that R recycles vectors:

```
ix <- (substr(df$GazeCue,1,1) == substring(df$TargetLocation,7)) + 1
df$CueType <- c("Uncued","Cued")[ix]
```

Comment: A bit cryptic and hacky, but it is faster than `ifelse`. I'd use `substr` in both cases for clarity, but that's more style than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
edata[,3] <- NA #add a new column
names(edata)[3] <- "CueType" #add a name column

for (i in 1 : nrow(edata)) {
  if (edata$GazeCue[i] == 'RightGazePic1.png' & edata$TargetLocation[i]==
'TargetR') {
    edata[i,3] <- "Cued"
  } else if (edata$GazeCue[i] == 'LeftGazePic1.png' & data$TargetLocation[i]
=='TargetL') {
    edata[i,3] <- "Cued"
  }
  else {
    edata[i,3] <- "Uncued"
  }
}
```

Test, it should work properly!